# Why were so many of my answers removed and reps subtracted?

Tags: discussion

I noticed that my reps had been lowered and when I checked my profile there were several of my answers which had been removed and reps deducted, and so I wonder what policy requires that and why?

Comment: Wax's answer pretty solidly covers this one. Then only thing I would add is to answer why now and not last week or the week before — site cleanup work has been piling up for a while and I finally got through some of it while staying up till 4am last night to catch the creationism debate.

Comment: @Caleb Thank you I can appreciate your predicament This is an active site, and I'm sure it takes a lot of your time cleaning it up. Please believe that I am not criticizing anyone. I appreciate all the help I have gotten from everyone, I am still learning and probably will as long  as I live.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Four of your positively scored answers were deleted last night. However, this was due to the *question* getting deleted, not anything about your answers specifically.

Two things worth mentioning:

- If your posts get to +3 and the post is older than 30 days, then the reputation is kept. That wasn't the case in any of these cases (all posts were <3 scored so age is irrelevant).
- Answering questions that are likely to get closed/deleted carries the risk that you will lose reputation when they are inevitably deleted. Not only that, your work is wasted because it's not longer generally accessible. Instead of answering these, action them, you have the reputation to vote to close, use it.

Note that this also works in reverse, if you have a net loss of reputation when a post is deleted then you'll regain that reputation.

Comment: Thank you, I still have a lot to learn about this site. Some of it was worth the chance of losing them just to make my point, and it really isn't a great loss. It is good to know that.

Comment: @CecilBeckum please take this answer as a bit of a warning then. We don't want *anyone* answering questions that will be closed/deleted. That's not useful for this site, it's a waste of time for you, and, really, it doesn't actually help the person asking the question. You're a high rep user now, you have close votes. Resist the urge to answer and cast a close vote. It's the *right thing to do*. Posting an answer to "make a point" is the wrong kind of behavior here. Thanks.

Comment: I understand and will comply in the future, that was in regard to the deleted items.